# PhantomJS font rendering

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, webfonts, truetype

Can PhantomJS render truetype font that are embedded in the webpage?
I have my css like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Roboto-Regular.ttf'), url('Roboto-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Issue listed on github: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10592

Comment: Thanks Bowerbros. that was useful.

Comment: Apparently this has been fixed in version 2.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is "it depends".  Phantomjs, as a "headless" browser, is similar to any other browser in that it can only render fonts like the above if that font is installed on the system doing the rendering.  If I have Roboto installed on my machine when I hit your web page, then I will see Roboto as expected.  If, however, I do not have Roboto installed on my local machine, it will render whatever default, fallback font my browser uses.

Phantomjs is more than capable of rendering Google fonts, like Roboto, if you load them as external fonts, linked from a 3rd party website.  Or, better yet, use https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader which will do the heavy lifting of loading webfonts for you.

As of Phantomjs 2.0, phantomjs is able to render "[websafe](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp)" fonts. However, this will again depend upon whether those fonts are installed on the machine in question.  If, for example, your webserver is running a flavor of Linux, you may have issues.  This is because the "websafe" fonts are actually Microsoft fonts and have been licensed for use by operating systems like Windows and OSX.  Such fonts are not necessarily installed in other operating systems and may need to be installed manually, as described [here](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Web browsers can render fonts that aren't installed on your machine. That's the whole idea behind [fontfaces](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).

Answer (score 0):

because header footer and content are rnedering separate you need to include the fonts in each part.

please follow the example and get the font result in your header

add this at the header :

```
"<style> "+
                        "@font-face {"+
                        " format('ttf'); "+
                        "font-family: 'Open Sans'; "+
                        "font-style: normal; "+
                        "font-weight: 400; "+
                        "src: url(" + url + "/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf)  format('truetype');"+
                        "} " +
                "* { font-family: 'Open Sans'; } </style > "
```

the parameter url is define with the path to phantomjs.exe running, and you declare it with :

```
url = 'file:///' + fs.absolute('./');
```

should work in header,

hope it help anyone

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time to fix similar problem. I had `@font-face` defined with various urls (absolute paths, relative, http url etc),  and nothing worked. Everything started working after putting all fonts in `~/.fonts` directory, removing all `@font-face` declaration in CSS and using only `font-family`. It was on CentOS Linux distribution (with `phantomjs-prebuilt` module, version: 2.1.16), but i think it will work on other too.

```
html, body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    zoom: 0.70; /* fix for too large fonts */   
} 

$ ls ~/.fonts/
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   4096 06-03 15:16 .
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root   4096 04-15 13:56 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  11358 2017-05-26  LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 175888 2017-05-26  RobotoCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 169800 2017-05-26  RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 175188 2017-05-26  RobotoCondensed-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 175380 2017-05-26  RobotoCondensed-LightItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 168004 2017-05-26  RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 170284 2017-05-26  RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf
```